# Capabilities of JavaScript in iOS Shortcuts

Tags: ios, safari, development, shortcuts-app, javascript

According to this:

https://support.apple.com/en-eg/guide/shortcuts/apd218e2187d/ios

And this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore

And this:

https://medium.com/@chrishutchinson/hacking-around-with-javascript-and-shortcuts-in-ios-12-95f8d7190777

It seems like the JavaScript allowed in apple applications like Scriptable and Shortcuts is like, “pure” JavaScript (as a programming language), which somehow does not support importing any modules or packages.

The problem is I don’t know enough about how JavaScript works to grasp this intuitively.

I am pretty sure Apple’s JavaScriptCore is syntactically based on ECMAScript 6 https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/.

As far as I can tell, you cannot call `fetch()` in Scriptable, or in iOS Shortcuts’ “Run JavaScript on Webpage”.

It implies there are some JavaScript classes or methods that are not available, but I don’t know how to anticipate which ones.

How can I understand precisely specifically what JavaScript commands are supported and which aren’t, and why?

Am I supposed to take WebKit as my documentation, perhaps? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs

https://webkit.org/blog/7536/jsc-loves-es6/

But if I am running JavaScript on a Safari page from iOS Shortcuts, wouldn’t I have full access to the client-side JavaScript capabilities of the browser, and doesn’t that naturally include basic Web APIs, like fetch()?